# Source code style checks as part of unit tests?

Tags: java, unit-testing, reflection

I would like to ask if it is possible (and normal) somehow to check the project code itself in java unit tests. I want to check if there are unused methods, lack of checks etc.

So a group of my unit tests will have the purpose of validating that the classes are written according to the conventions

I can get the methods via reflection, but not each separate statement

Comment: May be worth a try :[sonarlint](https://www.sonarlint.org/)

Answer (score 3):

If I right understand your problem, you should use "checkstyle" plugin for example for maven is it:

```
            <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-checkstyle-plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                        <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>install</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>check</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

Where `"checkstyle.xml"` is your rules for validation and `<phase>install</phase>` is your maven goal for execute checkstyle phase.

for more information [see](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately checkstyle is limited, and i want to do some custom things, like test that all classes in a package do not have code in the default constructor (just an example) as this is a very large team and noone can check everything. So essentially i need some way to get source code info from inside java unit tests

Comment: @dac1n You’ll want to write a [custom check](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/writingchecks.html).